# Sublime Text - One Command Minify/Upload

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I've started using SublimeText recently and am trying to figure out whether it's possible to combine a minify/beautify process with a save/auto-upload.

Right now, I've installed the "minify" package (which creates a new file with an additional extension of ".min"), and I've also (separately) turned on auto-upload on save.  So I'm running the minify command, then opening the file created, and then saving it to trigger the upload.

What would be great if there was a way for me to be editing a big messy html/css/js file (with comments, spaces etc), and then in a single command trigger a process that both ran the minify plugin AND  uploaded the minifed version to my server.

Worth pointing out that the minify plugin has these 2 settings which don't quite achieve what I'm looking for...

```
// Save file before doing any action (minify or beautify)?
    "save_first": false,

    // Auto-minify files on save?
    "auto_minify_on_save": true,
```

(The problem being that the newly created auto-minified file doesn't auto-upload to the server - the above settings just allow a separate minifed file to be generated, while the original non-minified is uploaded automatically!)

Might sound like a small improvement, but I'm pretty sure it would save me a bunch of time over the weeks and months if I could combine these 2 operations.  Anyone managed something similar in Sublime Text?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You *should* be able to record a [macro](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/macros.html) if your `minify` and `upload_to_server` commands are well-defined. To record a macro, follow these steps:

1. Select **`Tools → Record Macro`**, or use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> on OS X or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> on Windows and Linux.
2. Run your Minify command, then your Save/Upload to Server command, then hit the above key combo again, or select **`Tools → Stop Recording Macro`**.
3. Select **`Tools → Save Macro…`** and save it in your `Packages/User` folder (it should select it automatically) as `minify_save_upload.sublime-macro`.
4. Open the macro by selecting **`Preferences → Browse Packages…`** to open your `Packages` folder in your operating system's file manager, then navigate to the `User` folder and open the file you saved above in Sublime with JSON syntax. It should look something like this:

   ```js
   [
       {
           "args": null,
           "command": "minify"
       },
       {
           "args": null,
           "command": "save"
       },
       {
           "args": null,
           "command": "upload_to_server"
       }
   ]
   ```

   Since you didn't say what plugin you're using to do the upload I'm not sure what command will be there, but hopefully it'll all work as expected.
5. The macro will now be available under **`Tools → Macros → User → minify_save_upload`**. To access it more easily, you can make a [custom key binding](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/macros.html#key-binding-for-macros) by selecting **`Preferences → Key Bindings—User`** and adding the following after the opening bracket `[`:

   ```js
   {
       "keys": ["ctrl+alt+shift+s"], 
       "command": "run_macro_file", 
       "args": 
       {
           "file": "Packages/User/minify_save_upload.sublime-macro"
       }
   },
   ```

   If this is the only entry in your custom key bindings, you can remove the trailing comma `,` after the final closing curly brace `}`, otherwise it should stay.
6. Run the macro to ensure it works, and you should be all set!